# Ignore null results in MySQL JOIN queries

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a MySQL join query which works well ***(disclaimer: taken from tutorial)***:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "test") or die("Error connecting to database");
    mysql_select_db("products90", $connection);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buyers LEFT JOIN products USING (id);", $connection) or die("error querying database");
    $i = 0;
    while($result_ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <table>
    <tr <?php if($i%2 == 1){ echo "class='body2'"; }else{echo "class='body1'";}?>>
    <td>
    <?php echo $result_ar['buyer_name']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $result_ar['manufacturer']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $result_ar['product_name']; ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    $i+=1;
    }
    ?>
```

However, *if* I wanted it to ignore NULL results, what would I need to do with the JOIN, which type is appropriate?

I had a look on Google, but am not sure where to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2):

By saying you want to ignore NULL results what exactly do you mean?  Are you saying that when your left join executes you're getting some buyers which NULL next to them *where products would be* (had they bought some)?

In that case what you're looking for is an INNER JOIN which will **only show values if it has a match in the other**.

Comment: If a product is discontinued I've made the column NULL - database has a copy made of it, this is a testing copy.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have null results, you mean where there are no products?

Anyway, if you have null IDs, therefore, no result in products, you could just also add

```
where products.id is not null
```

or, you could change the join from left join to just join, making it an inner join

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM buyers LEFT JOIN products USING (id) WHERE products.id IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM buyers JOIN products USING (id)
```

Using `JOIN` only brings matched rows where as the `LEFT JOIN` brings all buyers regardless of any matches found in products and filters the records afterwards. I am not exactly sure about your scenario but it seems simpler to me to just use `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thanks, but what if I had two values - products.id and the product_name column - I just get the "error querying database" message.

Comment: well, you should only do LEFT JOINs when necessary, since the query optimizer cannot optimize them (order is important for LEFT JOINs). So you should go for the second query

Comment: @avenas8808 use `or die(mysql_error())` instead and it would output the accurate error.

Comment: @avenas8808 i think you should show us your DB schema of both tables. Seems to me that you don't have a foreign key in the products table from your above comment.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an INNER JOIN for that (if I got your question right).

For an overview of JOIN types in MySQL please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Thanks; what's the INNER JOIN query for this one then, that I can try?

Comment: SELECT ... FROM buyers INNER JOIN products USING (id)

Answer (score 0):

If  you want to ignore the null results then just use the `INNER JOIN`, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN`.
Change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM buyers JOIN products USING (id)
```