# Displaying links in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, image, echo, default-value

Thank you for answering my question at [Ignore null results in MySQL JOIN queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700784/ignore-null-results-in-mysql-join-queries)

I've created my own radio station website in localhost, at http://myradiostation.localhost

This is the code:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "PASSWORD") or die("Error connecting to database");
    mysql_select_db("radio1", $connection);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM presenters;", $connection) or die("error querying database");
    $i = 0;
    while($result_ar = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
```

This is the HTML code:

```
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="main" style="width:552px;">
                <img src="<?php echo $result_ar['image']; ?>" width=115 height=60>
                <div class="time"><?php echo $result_ar['airtime']; ?></div>
                <div class="show"><h3><b><a href="<?php echo $result_ar['link']; ?>"><?php echo $result_ar['presenter']; ?></a></b></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $result_ar['showinfo']; ?></p></div>
                <div class="footer"></div>
            </div>
    <?php
    $i+=1;
    }
    ?>
```

It **does** work, except for one thing - the content without links still links back to the page itself, even though the database columns have some blank content.

Here's the SQL code - create a database called radio1 in PHPmyadmin and this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `presenters` (
  `presenter` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `airtime` time NOT NULL,
  `showinfo` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `presenters`
--

INSERT INTO `presenters` (`presenter`, `link`, `image`, `airtime`, `showinfo`) VALUES
('Non-Stop Nightshift', '', '', '01:00:00', 'More Music Variety through your weekend'),
('Greatest Hits', '', '', '06:00:00', 'Hit Music now!'),
('John Doe', 'http://www.myradiostation.localhost/johndoe', '', '08:00:00', 'Join John at the weekend');
```

It works with no major issues, except the linking one.

It displays properly, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b91Dj.jpg

How can I fix this? (if there's no images I suppose I could set a default value in the field though), and what would you recommend?

In short, how should I store HTML links in a PHPMyadmin database?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the entirety of your code? Where do your anchor (`<a>`) tags begin?

Comment: <div class="show"><h3><b><a href="<?php echo $result_ar['link']; ?>"><?php echo $result_ar['presenter']; ?></a></b></h3> is the code with the anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a conditional statement to detect rows without links. Something like this:

```
<div class="show"><h3><b>
<?php
if ( empty( $result_ar['link'] ) ) {
    echo $result_ar['presenter'];
}
else {
    echo '<a href="' . $result_ar['link'] . '">' . $result_ar['presenter'] . '</a>';
}
?>
</b></h3>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I replace the code within the original coding then?

Comment: @avenas8808: You can replace the line `<div class="show"><h3><b><a href="<?php echo $result_ar['link']; ?>"><?php echo $result_ar['presenter']; ?></a></b></h3>` with the code above.

Comment: Tried that; got this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\www\vhosts\localradio\schedsun.php on line 13**

Comment: There was a missing right-parenthesis. I updated the answer. More importantly, do you understand what I did here? If the link field in the DB is empty, we are just outputing the name. Otherwise, we construct and output a link.

Comment: It almost works, but got this error: 08:00:00
"John Doe - not sure why the quotation mark is still there though ? @George Cummins, I do understand, thanks for your help.

Comment: There is either an extraneous quotation mark in the area where you pasted the code (perhaps around the `<div class="show"><h3><b>`) or the quotation mark is in the database row itself. If you want to append your new code to your answer, I can help you find it.

Comment: I see nothing in that code that would introduce the quotation mark.

Comment: I think I do: on line 18: there is an extra double quote after the closing `>` for the link tag (`$result_ar['link'] . '">"'` ) should be ( `$result_ar['link'] . '">'` )

Answer (score 0):

Its not a PHP or MySQL problem. It's HTML 101. Whenever there is an `<a 
href="">` tag, it will link to that page if it's blank. I believe that this will fix it:
`<php>
If $array['link '] echo '<a>'`
You can make it a bit neater,  but this is the basic idea.