# Highlighting DIV element at certain times using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, syntax-highlighting, if-statement

I have a **radio station site** done in PHP, as mentioned at [Displaying strtotime() effectively in MySQL/PHP query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713552/displaying-strtotime-effectively-in-mysql-php-query).

It's working now (new code at http://pastebin.com/TyB2v18R), but only one issue needs to be done:

http://pastebin.com/ZPj1uJFx

(this is how I think it should render at certain times of the day).

My schedule has shows at the following times:

> 01:00
>
> 06:00
>
> 08:00
>
> 12:00
>
> 16:00
>
> 19:00
>
> 22:00

What should I do to get it to **highlight** it at these specific times in this script?
Is ifelse the solution?

Thank you for your help, learning a lot and getting it working too!

Answer (score 0):

when generating the HTML, add a CSS class to the times that should be highlighted.

Comment: Since this is from MySQL/PHP, how can I apply the dividercurrent/maincurrent CSS classes?

Comment: perhaps I don't understand your question, but you can do: <div class="time<?php if ($result_arr['time'] == xxx)echo " your_highlight_class"; ?>">the time</div>

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to get it to highlight it at these specific times in
>   this script? Is ifelse the solution?

To get hightlighting at these specified times you could use  [CSS pseudo class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) at those times

Your HTML would something like this:

```
<div class="hightlight">Hello World</div>
```

Your [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) would look something like

```
.hightlight {
  color: yellow;
}
```

With this cide you would hightlight the `div` "Hello World" yellow.

You could see this jsfiddle for example => http://jsfiddle.net/YdtBr/