# PHP Converting Integer to Date, reverse of strtotime

Tags: php, date, time, type-conversion, strtotime

```
<?php
echo strtotime("2014-01-01 00:00:01")."<hr>";
// output is 1388516401
?>
```

I am surprised if it can be reverse. I mean can I `convert 1388516401 to 2014-01-01 00:00:01`.
What I actually want to know is, what's the logic behind this conversion. How php convert date to a specific integer.

Comment: `$time = 1388516401; echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);` I'd like to refer you to the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: hmmm, good question title, but the question itself is useless.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes you can convert it back. You can try:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1388516401);
```

The logic behind this conversion from date to an integer is explained in [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) in PHP:

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

For example, `strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:00")` gives you 0 and `strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:01")` gives you 1.

This means that if you are printing `strtotime("2014-01-01 00:00:01")`  which will give you output `1388516401`, so the date `2014-01-01 00:00:01` is 1,388,516,401 seconds after January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: I have this integer `-243219600` which is relative to **18/04/1962** when I convert it `date('d/m/Y', $r)` it gives me the date **17/04/1962**

Comment: strtotime("1970-01-01 00:00:00") only gives you 0 if your date_default_timezone is set to UTC -- both parameters from strtotime take the default timezone into its calculation

Answer (score 15):

Can you try this,

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1388516401);
```

As noted by [theGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713552/displaying-strtotime-effectively-in-mysql-php-query/6713630#6713630),

> This means that you pass in a string value for the time, and optionally a value for the current time, which is a UNIX timestamp. The value that is returned is an integer which is a UNIX timestamp.

```
echo strtotime("2014-01-01 00:00:01");
```

This will return into the value 1388516401, which is the UNIX timestamp for the date 2014-01-01. This can be confirmed using the date() function as like below:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', 1198148400); // echos 2014-01-01
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are asking why is 1388516401 equal to 2014-01-01...?

There is an historical reason for that. There is a 32-bit integer variable, called `time_t`, that keeps the count of the time elapsed since **1970-01-01 00:00:00**. Its value expresses time in *seconds*. This means that in **2014-01-01 00:00:01** `time_t` will be equal to **1388516401**.

This leads us for sure to another interesting fact...  In **2038-01-19 03:14:07** `time_t` will reach **2147485547**, the maximum value for a 32-bit number. Ever heard about [John Titor and the Year 2038 problem](http://www.johntitor.strategicbrains.com/TimeMachine.cfm)? :D

Answer (score 0):

The time() function displays the seconds between now and the unix epoch , 01 01 1970 (00:00:00 GMT). The strtotime() transforms a normal date format into a time() format. So the representation of that date into seconds will be : 1388516401

Source: http://www.php.net/time