# Convert integer to date in mysql ,php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 columns one having month and another year , I want to get all the records greater than that month and year

I cannot use date functions as those columns are of integer type, It gives incorrect results

How can I get records greater than that month and year

For example How can I get events which took place after february 2017

Comment: What you have tried earlier?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617100/php-converting-integer-to-date-reverse-of-strtotime

Comment: Would be better if you post your code

Comment: @Harsh Barach TRIED select *, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('joining_month','joining_year'),'%m,%Y') AS entry_date from event WHERE entry_date >'2-2016'  But entry_date is NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this approach:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(year, month) > 201702
```

Answer (score -1):

`WHERE CONCAT(year, month) > 201702`

probably you have also some php code inside so:

```
$date = strtotime('2018-01-01 01:01:01');
$sql =  'SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE 
          WHERE CONCAT(year, month) > ' . date('Ym', $date);
```

Comment: And what if the date is, for example, january 2018?

Comment: You didn't understand correctly - if I want everything with date greater than 02/2017, but in the DB is record with the month 01, year 2018. Your code won't select it...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE CONCAT(year,month) >= 201702
```

or without CONCAT

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE( month > 2 AND year =2017) OR (year > 2017)
```

Comment: And what if the date in the DB record is, for example, month 01, year 2018?