# Yii2 framework: how to format/convert Integer to Date

Tags: php, date, integer, unix-timestamp, yii2-advanced-app

I need to convert an integer number to date using the **Yii2 Framework for PHP**.

I can convert it using the PHP function like this (as I found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617100/php-converting-integer-to-date-reverse-of-strtotime)):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1498675028);
```

But I am new using Yii2 so I am not sure how to do it and maybe it can be done with Yii2.

I have a table with some columns and two of them (*created_at* and *updated_at*) has the integer 1498675028 (it is in the Unix time stamp format). But the user see in the view the integer number instead of a date. This is part of my *index.php* view file:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'username',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <?php Pjax::begin(); ?> 

    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'username',
        'created_at:date',
        'updated_at:date',
        [
          'attribute' => 'updated_at',
           'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                      return date('Y-m-d', $model->updated_at);
            },
       ], 
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: @Roby Sottini - Follow this code  'created_at:date',
        'updated_at:date',

Comment: It works, but it is shown in a English way: Jun 28, 2017. Can it be formatted?